# alternative to CutyCapt

Tags: java, cutycapt

is there is any alternative to Cutycapt..that can be access using java library....

In short, Cutycapt is a cross-platform command-line utility to capture WebKit's rendering of a web page into a variety of vector and bitmap formats, including SVG and PNG ([1](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: You'd be better off explaning what CutyCapt does, as I don't know how many people have heard of it before (I certainly haven't)

Comment: ohh ok that captures(Screenshort) an webpage and saves it in your localdisk..http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm interested in answers as well!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Webkit for SWT](http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs-webkit-for-swt/WebKit%20For%20SWT%20Developer%20Guide.html) as a starting point for a Java Library for WebKit. One drawback, however, is that it isn't cross platform.

[Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) is a pure Java solution, but you will likely not get the same rendering quality or performance as WebKit.

A final option is [JDIC](http://java.net/projects/jdic/sources). It doesn't appear to be under active development, but there is a nice article from IBM [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdic/) about it.

Comment: All of these projects aren't activly developed anymore :(